# Compiling Problem - LyX LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, lyx, compiling, moderncv

I have always used LyX LaTeX to create my resumé. I changed my laptop and I'm trying to install the program in the new one. For some reason that I don't understand, I can't compile into a PDF format.

When I try it, it appears this error message:

> I can't find file `switch.def'.

and the descriptions says:

> \input switch.def\relax     Please type another input file name

I'm a very basic laptop user. I don't know anything about programming.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try to install the `babel` package. Probably you have installed LyX without  MikTeX in Windoews, or you have a new installation of MikTEX with only some packages. Probably that package will be downloaded and installed automatically if you try to compile again the same file, but otherwise you can force the installation of babel using the MikTeX tools.

Comment: Hi Fran, thank you so much for your help : ) Before installing LyX I inslalled the lasted version of MikTeX for Windows. Just checked in the MikTeX console andI have the Babel package is installed... any more ideas?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer a few years ago you helped me with some issues with Lyx. Do you have any idea what might be happening now?

Comment: No, you will have to provide a log-file.

Comment: @ManuelaLorenzo Tools > Reconfigure. Restart. Make a new file with just "Hello, word" and check if that can be compiled with Ctrl+R. If this fail mean that Lyx Is unable lo locate the route to Miktex files.  If this work, just change the language setting to Spanish, check in the View >  Code Preview Pane that is added  ``\usepackage{babel}` and try to compile again. If the error appear then, Lyx is unable lo locate the route to  babel files. Check  in Tools > TeX information > LaTeX styles  with "Show Path" checked  if LyX have found the right path to `babel.sty`.